Detecting sections of sinusoids of varying frequency in time domain waveform
I have time domain waveforms as shown here:

Around ~11:54 and ~11:59 are sinusoids and in between is "noise". I would like to obtain an indicator function that's 1 when when there is (likely) a sinusoid and 0 otherwise.
If the frequency of the sinusoid would be known I could just use a rolling cross correlation with thresholding. But since phase and frequency of the sinusoids can be "arbitrary" (subject to some constraints of course) I am not sure how to proceed. The amplitude should be roughly the same always (but not exactly since there is noise).
Background: The waveforms show the measured magnetic fields in x/y/z direction obtained from a magnetic sensor placed next to my water meter. A water meter contains a nutating disk with a magnet. When water flows, the disk wobbles up and down and creates a sinusoidal waveform. The higher the flow, the higher the frequency.
Ideally, when there is no flow, the magnetic field should not change (disk does not move). Hence a threshold is used to count "half rotations" of the disk and convert them to liters.
However, pressure fluctuations in the absence of a check valve (=backflow preventer) causes water to slowly move back and forth through the meter and the disk moves just slightly back and forth. On average, this should result in a net flow of zero. While the flow of water can also be seen by the "leak detector" on the meter (recording a video and playing fast forward), the dials on the meter do not count that net-zero flow. However, with the thresholding approach from above, the noise is recognized as disk rotation and hence I detect a water flow where there shouldn't be one.
Overall, the disk rotations should only be detected during the sections where there is a sinusoid (=actual water flow).

Is there a relatively narrow band of frequencies in which the oscillation can exist?

I don't think relatively narrow but if needed for a solution we can assume $f_{min}$ and $f_{max}$ exists. The maximum is given by the pipe diameter and max pressure. But lower bound is harder. A small leak would result in a fairly low frequency oscillation.

Could one assume that the length of period N is nearly the same as period N+1? I.e. that frequency change slowly? If so, what about measuring zero crossings and detecting periods of nearly constant zcr?

@divB: can you post the data (as a link to a txt or CSV file, etc)? I would want to some in to the oscillating parts and take a closer look whats going on there. If the oscillation is reasonably regular, than a short term Fourier transform should be able to detect it

@Hilmar here is raw data: https://justpaste.it/2h0i1 . Note it's without postprocessing and sample times are not uniform. But the times when water flows is clearly visible)
